# How to clear just variables defined in one notebook?

Tags: clear

I'm trying to set up some notebooks so that I have one "seed" notebook that defines all my values globally when I run it.  I have three other notebooks that take these values and run with them to do what they do.

Problem is, these notebooks solve for functions and define them locally.  I can't re-run these notebooks without running the seed book every time since Solve sees functions that are already defined.  Is there a way to clear JUST the variables I have defined in a notebook?

Edit: forgot to mention the seed notebook does a ``` ClearAll["Global``*"] ``` at the beginning.

Comment: I was trying to figure out what are "just variables"... Are these immanently just, or they become so when used by just programmers? I wonder who uses then the dishonest symbol table.

Answer (score 12):

The `` Global` `` context in a kernel is shared between notebooks communicating with that kernel, so issuing a `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` in one notebook will clear them from all notebooks.

As an alternative, you can define your "seed" notebook variables in a specific context (e.g. `` seed` ``) and then add that context to the global path. For example, in your seed notebook,

```
Begin["Seed`"];
    foo = 1;
    bar = 2;
End[];

AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Seed`"];
```

Now you can use these variables in your secondary notebooks without having to expressly qualify them as `` Seed`foo `` and simply do `` ClearAll["Seed`*"] `` to clear only these variables.

---

You can also set the seed notebook to have a unique context by choosing `Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to this Notebook`, which will then make its context something like `` Notebook$$12345` `` and you can append this to `$ContextPath` as above. However, having such a context name is both unsightly and not informative, so I'd suggest using explicitly (and appropriately) named contexts.

Comment: Hmmm... Sounds like I need to educate myself in the use of Contexts.  Your suggestion is a good one, but from what I can tell it's doing the opposite of what I need--allowing me to clear Seed when I want to clear, say, Case1 for my notebook test case.  Thanks though; it's a good start.

Comment: @SixtySuit Uh? I don't understand what you mean... If you need `Case1`, then make `Case1` a separate context.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a workaround but you can:

1) list all the Global variables like so: `` Names["Global`*"] ``

2) search you current notebook for specific strings

By searching your notebook, returning a list of all the positions where global variables are used and then searching for which instances there is an "=" directly after that variable you can get a list of all variables defined in the current notebook:

```
Take[Names["Global`*"], 
 Flatten[Position[{Off[StringTake::mseqs]; 
   StringTake[
      ToString[
       FindList[
        NotebookFileName[], #]], {Max[Flatten[
          StringPosition[FindList[NotebookFileName[], #], #]]] + 6}]
         & /@ Names["Global`*"], On[StringTake::mseqs]}[[1]], 
 "="]]]
```

Comment: It's a decent start, but there are several ways to define variables. For instance, `:=`, `/:`, `:^=`, etc.  You can also define several variables at once, as `{foo, bar, baz} = ...` Also, there's the possibility of strings such as `"foo = ..."` showing up as false positives.